# Golang unable to "sqlc generate"

Tags: go, environment-variables, backend, sqlc, goose

I am using windows and Ubuntu WSL but get this error when I try to sqlc generate.

```
sqlc generate
# package database
sql/schema/001_users.sql:1:1: the PostgreSQL engine requires cgo. Please set CGO_ENABLED=1.
```

```
export CGO_ENABLED=1 && sqlc generate
# package database
sql/schema/001_users.sql:1:1: the PostgreSQL engine requires cgo. Please set CGO_ENABLED=1.
```

When I try `go env` command, but it's in my environment but still not able to sqlc generate

```
go env

GO111MODULE=''
GOARCH='amd64'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/home/user/.cache/go-build'
GOENV='/home/user/.config/go/env'
.
.
.
GOHOSTARCH='amd64'
GOHOSTOS='linux'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/home/user/go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='linux'
GOPATH='/home/user/go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='https://proxy.golang.org,direct'
GOROOT='/usr/local/go'
GOSUMDB='sum.golang.org'
.
.
.
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/Golang/main/go.mod'
```

Comment: you are not answering my questions and solving my problem, you are here just to act like a boss and contributing nothing on this post. 
And for future reference: No one here cares how you feel about how I feel about "{ChatGPT, or the current cost of gasoline, or any other opinion. Leave the noise out of your view on my questions.}"

Comment: @KenWhite where does the OP have quotes around `1` in the environment variable declaration?

Comment: @KenWhite it's not declaration, it's output of the `go env`, and that's how `go env` outputs environment variables in its output - with a single quote character around. Just check yourself. `CGO_ENABLED=0 go env|grep CGO_ENABLED // outputs CGO_ENABLED='0'`

Comment: @许家宝's I believe the error has to do with the `sqlc` executable itself. Where did you get it? How did you compile it?

Comment: @zerkms Really thanks for your reply! I'm learning Go from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=un6ZyFkqFKo&t=26601s)  at 7:23:21 I follow how it does, go install github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/cmd/sqlc@latest and able to run sqlc version. And I'm using windows system with Ubuntu WSL to run "sqlc generate"

Comment: I'm not sure if it requires to follow [instructions](https://www.bytebase.com/blog/how-to-cross-compile-with-cgo-use-goreleaser-and-github-action/) to cross compile with CGO using GoReleaser for "sqlc generate" command to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to duplicate this on a fresh install of WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 (running on Win 11). With the fresh image I installed Go (1.21.4) & `sqlc` (v1.23.0) then ran `sqlc generate` (using the example repo from the tutorial mentioned in the question) and got the error:

```
# package database
sql/schema/001_users.sql:1:1: the PostgreSQL engine requires cgo. Please set CGO_ENABLED=1.
sql/schema/002_users_apikey.sql:1:1: the PostgreSQL engine requires cgo. Please set CGO_ENABLED=1.
sql/schema/003_feeds.sql:1:1: the PostgreSQL engine requires cgo. Please set CGO_ENABLED=1.
```

Interestingly everything worked fine under Ubuntu 20.04 (also on WSL2).

There is an [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57328) with the compatibility of CGO enabled binaries across Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 (did not look at the issue in any real detail!); so it seemed worth trying to re-install `sqlc` with `CGO` enabled:

```
go env -w CGO_ENABLED=1
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc
go install github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/cmd/sqlc@latest
```

After doing this `sqlc` worked (successfully generated the `go` files for the `6-createfeed` example without issue).

Note: As this worked I thought I'd add comments to any similar [sqlc issues](https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/issues) and came across [this comment](https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/issues/2149#issuecomment-1703982061) suggesting the same basic solution (did not spot this when I looked last night).

Comment: wow bro, it works! Thanks a lot!!